# 2 same string are not equal in bash

Tags: bash

I'm trying to test if the output of a program is equal to something, so that I can do something based on it. The console prints that the 2 values are equal, but the condition is not met.

Here's the code:

```
#!/bin/bash

test_id=`clasp run testRunner`

function get_logs() {
  echo "trying to get logs for test id $test_id..."

  logs=`clasp logs`

  if logs_contain_test_id
  then
    print_logs
  else
    get_logs
  fi
}

function logs_contain_test_id() {
  IFS=$' '
  for log in $logs
  do
    echo $log
    echo $test_id
    if [[ "$log" == "$test_id" ]]
    then
      return 0
    fi
  done
  return 1
}

get_logs
```

Note that this line `echo "trying to get logs for test id $test_id..."` only prints the id like `"03443db8..."` and not the full sentence.

Also the `echo $log` and `echo $test_id` log `03443db8` `03443db8` on 2 separate lines so they should be equal.

How can I debug this? Seems like some hidden characters are part of `$test_id`

The condition print_logs never gets activated, even if both returns print equal to the console. I am on a mac if it makes any difference.

Here's the strange output I am getting:

```
tests,
03443db8
0
03443db8
failures,
03443db8
03443db8
03443db8
03443db8... <-- this should be "trying to get logs for test id 03443db8..."
```

edit: after adding `set -x` I get these logs:

```
+ [[ failures, == \[\2\K\[\1\G\4\4\f\a\7\0\c\7 ]]
+ for log in '$logs'
+ echo 44fa70c7
44fa70c7
44fa70c7'
44fa70c7
+ [[ 44fa70c7 == \[\2\K\[\1\G\4\4\f\a\7\0\c\7 ]]
+ return 1
+ get_logs
44fa70c7...'
44fa70c7...
++ clasp logs
```

Comment: Looks like $test_id is prefixed with \r. You can debug with hd <<<“$test_id”. But I would use grep instead of your search function altogether.

Comment: Also, `IFS=' '` is explicitly telling the shell to treat *only* normal whitespace, and not newline literals, as word separators. That... doesn't seem likely to be what one would want. Then again, using `for` to process line-oriented input is a bad idea in the first place; see [DontReadLinesWithFor](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I just want to reset it. I would want to have scoped IFS=$'\n' only for the not included print_logs function but I don't know how.

Comment: Is that color in your output of clasp? Try turning it off, with something like —no-color, or similar.

Comment: @randomir there's no documented ways to remove colors that I see. how can I trim it?

Comment: You could run it through tr to remove non-alphanumerics. Or sed. Or grep with -O to extract just the pattern you’re interested in (the id).

Comment: So, the *default* value is `IFS=$' \t\n'`, not `IFS=' '`. To scope it, just put `local IFS` at the top of your function, before changing it.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14684/removing-control-chars-including-console-codes-colours-from-script-output might help with colorized text.

Answer (score 0):

Add `set -x` to your script then you can trace it.  See [Bash Manual: The Set Builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html#The-Set-Builtin) for more details.  In your case the script would be:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
test_id=`clasp run testRunner`

function get_logs() {
  set -x
  echo "trying to get logs for test id $test_id..."

  logs=`clasp logs`

  if logs_contain_test_id
  then
    print_logs
  else
    get_logs
  fi
}

function logs_contain_test_id() {
  set -x
  IFS=$' '
  for log in $logs
  do
    echo $log
    echo $test_id
    if [[ "$log" == "$test_id" ]]
    then
      return 0
    fi
  done
  return 1
}

get_logs
```

Comment: `function funcname() {` is combining legacy ksh syntax -- `function funcname {` -- with POSIX sh syntax -- `funcname() {` -- in a way that isn't compatible with *either* ksh or POSIX. See http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete

Comment: I added the output from set -x, do you know what the problem is?

Comment: I'd also suggest declaring `local IFS`; and there's no point to using `$''` quoting when all you're putting in it is a space.